# Expose struct generated from quote macro without appearing out of nowhere

Tags: rust, struct, macros, rust-macros

How can I expose a struct generated from the [`quote`](https://crates.io/crates/quote) macro in my derive macro without having to introduce a struct name out of the blue in my usage file (due to macro expansion)?

To illustrate the point, currently, my code looks something like this:

```rust
// "/my_derive/lib.rs"
// inside a derive macro function
let tokens = quote! {
  struct MyDeriveMacroInternalStruct {
    variant: #ident_name,
    // other stuff ...
  }
  impl #ident_name {
    pub fn something() -> Vec<MyDeriveMacroInternalStruct> {
      vec![MyDeriveMacroInternalStruct { variant: #ident_name::#variant_name, /*...*/ }, /*...*/]
    }
  }
};

tokens.into()
```

The usage of my code would look something like this:

```rust
use my_derive::MyDerive;

#[derive(MyDerive)]
enum Something {
  A,
  B,
  C,
}

fn process_data() -> Vec<MyDeriveMacroInternalStruct> { // having to write that struct name that came out of nowhere bothers me
  Something::something()
}

fn main() {
  let result = process_data();
  // do stuff...
}
```

This is a condensed version of my actual code (`process_data` is in another file). **To reiterate my question in light of the example**, how can I access the struct without having it randomly appear out of nowhere (due to macro expansion)? To me the code unchanged is hard to understand, read, and change.

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```rs
use my_derive::{MyDerive, MyDeriveStruct};

#[derive(MyDerive)]
enum Something {
  A,
  B,
  C,
}

fn process_data() -> Vec<MyDeriveStruct> { // importing the struct instead of magically appearing
  Something::something()
}

fn main() {
  let result = process_data();
  // do stuff...
}
```

Obviously the idea seems quite stupid, but there has to be a way around it (an arbitrary struct definition). If what I imagined isn't possible, is there some way to be more clear about where the random struct came from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I thought of something better. Your derive should probably be associated with a trait of the same name.

Add an associated type to your trait:

```rust
trait MyDerive {
    type Output;
    ...
}
```

Then set the associated type when you impl the trait:

```rust
  struct MyDeriveMacroInternalStruct {
    variant: #ident_name,
    // other stuff ...
  }

  impl MyDerive for #ident_name {
    type Output = MyDeriveMacroInternalStruct;

    pub fn something() -> Vec<MyDeriveMacroInternalStruct> {
      vec![MyDeriveMacroInternalStruct { variant: #ident_name::#variant_name, /*...*/ }, /*...*/]
    }
  }
```

Then you can refer to that associated type in return position or wherever:

```rust
use my_derive::MyDerive;

#[derive(MyDerive)]
enum Something {
  A,
  B,
  C,
}

fn process_data() -> Vec<<Something as MyDerive>::Output> {
  Something::something()
}

fn main() {
  let result = process_data();
  // do stuff...
}
```

**Note:** the convention is for `#[derive(Trait)]` to correspond to an impl for the given `Trait`, but your proc macro crate can't export a trait directly for importing in your library code.

So generally the solution is to have two crates:

- `my-trait` is the "library" crate which contains the `MyTrait` trait definition

  - `my-trait-derive` is the proc-macro crate which contains the derive macro code

`my-trait` has `my-trait-derive` as a direct dependency, and re-exports the proc macro from it:

```rust
// my-trait lib.rs

pub use my_trait_derive::MyTrait;

// macro and trait names can overlap as they're 
// treated as different item kinds
pub trait MyTrait {
    type Output;
    
    fn something();
}
```

[see how clap does it here](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/blob/a86e55ad3ed53d69c874e04f92d19092298f764f/src/lib.rs#L117) (they also re-export the whole `clap_derive`)

Then a user can use your proc macro + trait like this:

```rust
use my_trait::MyTrait;

#[derive(MyTrait)]
enum Something {}

fn process_data() -> Vec<<Something as MyTrait>::Output> {
  Something::something()
}
```

---

**Older Answer**

What I would do is create a trait `MyDeriveOutput` or something with whatever stuff you want exposed from `MyDeriveMacroInternalStruct`:

```rust
trait MyDeriveOutput {
    fn variant() ...
}
```

And then generate an impl for each internal struct you create:

```rust
struct MyDeriveMacroInternalStruct {
    variant: #ident_name,
    // other stuff ...
}
impl MyDeriveOutput for MyDeriveMacroInternalStruct {
    // whatever
}
```

Then you can expose the trait and require it to be imported and used with `impl Trait` in return position:

```rust
use my_derive::{MyDerive, MyDeriveOutput};

#[derive(MyDerive)]
enum Something {
  A,
  B,
  C,
}

fn process_data() -> Vec<impl MyDeriveOutput> {
  Something::something()
}

fn main() {
  let result = process_data();
  // do stuff...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, actually I'm not sure how practical your answer is: see, proc macro crates only allow you to export functions with the `proc_macro` or `proc_macro_derive` attributes (you can only export macro expanders). Any solution for that?

Comment: You'll have to put the trait in a separate "library" crate. I think generally the "library" crate is used as the main entry point, and the proc macro is re-exported from it.

Comment: Okay, so technically only the original answer works? I'm slightly confused now...

Comment: Well both answers require a trait from somewhere, so they don't differ in that factor. It really depends on whether you want your derive to follow the convention of `#[derive(Trait)] == impl Trait for`

Comment: I'm sorry, I've started Rust recently and am not familiar with all the concepts. Would you mind explaining?

Comment: Generally, the argument to `#[derive()]` is a trait, and the result of executing that proc macro is implementing the given trait for that type. `#[derive(Debug)] struct Thing` results in `impl Debug for Thing` being generated. This is the `#[derive(Trait)] == impl Trait` convention. So I'd recommend using the pattern in the first answer, and putting `fn something()` on the `MyDerive` trait, rather than implementing it directly on the target type as you are currently.

Comment: Oh my goodness, it worked perfectly. Thank you so much!!